# Changing Twiml instruction during the Twilio call

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am working an a Twilio app, and now building a feature to change Twiml instruction during the call.

So below will be a use case for it.

1. A user calls to a specific number for example 123-456-7890
2. When 123-456-7890 receives and answers the call, it should play some musics.
3. In a dashboard, I, an agent, should be able to change the music playing with other message instruction by clicking a button.
4. The replaced message should play until the call ends.

I tried to figure out a way to build this feature, but I wonder if it is technically possible or not. Thank you for reading my question. It will be really nice if any of you can give me some comments or feedbacks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can instruct a call to switch to executing a new TwiML.

You can do that by making a `POST` reuqest to Twilio's API, call instance resource.

With **curl**

```
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38 \
    -d "Url=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/new-voice.xml" \
    -d "Method=POST" \
    -u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```

---

or with **Node**

```
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls('CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38')
      .update({method: 'POST', url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/new-voice.xml'})
      .then(call => console.log(call.to))
      .done();
```

---

***Docs:***

- Call Redirection via the Twilio REST API

  - (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/09/call-queueing-putting-callers-on-hold-calll-redirect-new-url-new-feature.html)
- Modifying Live Calls

  - (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/modify-live-calls)

Comment: { [Error: Call is not in-progress. Cannot redirect. ]
  status: 400,
  message: 'Call is not in-progress. Cannot redirect. ',
  code: 21220,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21220',
  detail: undefined }